# An alternative to jsencrypt encryption with public key

Tags: reactjs, encryption, jsencrypt

I am currently using `jsencrypt` to encrypt text using a public key. This is what I have.

file.jsx

```
import JsEncrypt  from 'jsencrypt';
const textEncrypt = 'sensitive data';
const encrypt = new JsEncrypt.JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(key);
const encryptedText = encrypt.encrypt(textEncrypt);
...
```

Is there another library that can do this? I was reading about `crypto-js` but I am not sure if it does above.

```
import JsEncrypt from 'jsencrypt';
import Cryptico from "cryptico";

function jsencryptMethod() {
    const encrypt = new JsEncrypt.JSEncrypt();
    encrypt.setPublicKey('mykey');
    return encrypt.encrypt('DE52**0978');
}

function crypticoMethod(){
    return Cryptico.encrypt('DE52**0978', 'mykey');
}

it('should be equal', async () => {
    expect(jsencryptMethod()).toEqual(crypticoMethod());
});

Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: {"status": "Invalid public key"}
Received: false
```

Comment: JSEncrypt is a JavaScript library for RSA, i.e. for asymmetric encryption. `encrypt.encrypt(...)` actually returns the ciphertext (not just a boolean). You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt#how-to-use-this-library). CryptoJS is a JavaScript library for various cryptographic algorithms, especially symmetric encryption, but it doesn't support asymmetric encryption, so it does _not_ support RSA. The recommendation of libraries is off-topic. [Here](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441) is a link with a list of JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @Topaco I think cryptico might be able to do the job. What do you think? const encryptedText = Cryptico.encrypt(textEncrypt, key);

Comment: Cryptico implements a hybrid encryption, i.e. a combination of asymmetric and symmetric encryption, here RSA and AES. It's therefore no replacement for a _pure_ RSA implementation. Whether it still fits for your purposes depends on your overall requirements. One library that supports pure RSA is [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa) for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and OAEP, another [WebCryptoAPI](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsa-oaep) for OAEP.